# Count consecutive column data instances in Excel using formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I have an excel sheet which captures the number of orders that the Customer has made every month. I now require a column which populates the number of times when the customer made orders in 2 consecutive months. The excel looks something like this:

[image]

Here in the excel orders placed in consecutive months add up to the count. Say if I have orders in 4 consecutive months it sums to 2 in the count column and 3 shows up in the count column when there are orders for 6 consecutive months.

Taking Customer C1 as example, the first set of months with consecutive orders under them are April and May which map as 1. As we have already captured May in our calculation moving on from June the next set of consecutive months with orders that is encountered is August and September which map as 1. Moving ahead with October there are no more months with consecutive orders. So it sums to 2 for C1 which is mapped to Column M.

I have currently populated the column "M" data for reference but as the customer data becomes huge this is pretty tedious. I am trying to use **FREQUENCY** to do it but am somehow faltering to come up with a proper excel formula for this scenario. Can anyone help me this?

TIA

Comment: How do you get a result of 2 for the orders in 2 consecutive months for C1? There are apr&may, may&jun, aug&sep, sep&oct, which is 4... But you show a result of 2 in M2.

Comment: Here as April & May are considered as consecutive months. As May is already calculated the next set which starts from June is combined with July when there are no orders so the consecutive months is 1 here. The same applies for Sept,Oct and November where the consecutive is 1. This sums up to 2

Comment: November cannot be included as it is 0... You need to explain this clearly in the original question, not just leave it in a comment.

Comment: @SolarMike Have edited now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm thinking that you need to divide the frequencies (run lengths of consecutive orders) by 2 using integer division so

```
1->0
2->1
3->1
4->2
```

etc.

```
=SUM(QUOTIENT(FREQUENCY(IF($B2:$L2>0,COLUMN($B2:$L2)),IF($B2:$L2=0,COLUMN($B2:$L2))),2))
```

[image]

Again the formula has to be entered using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Now that's a very clever thought!

Comment: Well thank you for the formula which I borrowed and just tweaked a bit.

Answer (score 2):

You are making it quite hard on yourself, and I don't really know how this would be any easier than to calculate how ofter a streak of 2 occurs and add how ofter a streak of 4 occurs etc.etc.

A formula for counting streaks of minimum of two would look like:

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF($B2:$L2>0,COLUMN($B2:$L2)),IF($B2:$L2=0,COLUMN($B2:$L2)))>1,1))
```

Entered through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

To take into account the possibilities of a steak of 4, 6, 8, 10 or 12, you can check the above formula against a transposed array (done through seperating values with a semi-colon) like so:

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF($B2:$L2>0,COLUMN($B2:$L2)),IF($B2:$L2=0,COLUMN($B2:$L2)))>{1;3;5;7;9;11},1))
```

Entered through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

Maybe some mastermind can shorten this even further :)

Comment: @solarmike, you make it sound like you had no other choice haha. I tried SUMPRODUCT too with offset but it's proven too much

Comment: @sorry mate - it was meant as a compliment - now I re-read it I will delete it... I was hoping for the title of "mastermind"... but no luck :) ...

Comment: @SolarMike, I take no offence whatsoever! It sounded funny, if anything. On-topic, it's a tricky little puzzle this one :)

Comment: I would vote twice just for the effort shown, and tricky is right.